# SyntaxError: Cannot read property 'numerator' of undefined in pub\static\fron \package\theme\en_US\css\source\lib\_responsive.less

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, less, grunt

**SyntaxError: Cannot read property 'numerator' of undefined in**

pub\static\frontend\package\theme\en_US\css\source\lib_responsive.less

on line 44, column 9:

```
43     @media only screen and (max-width: (@screen__m - 1)) {
44         .media-width('max', @screen__m);
45     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some other invalid variable in the same .less file, inside that media query.